# Updating the sql server database in urdu(language) text

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am simply making a windows form in c# where I can insert, update and delete the data.

I want to insert data in URDU text. I am done with inserting data with following code :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblTeams values (@ID, @SchoolName, @TeamName)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtBoxID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolName", txtBoxSName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", txtBoxTName.Text);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

But when trying to update data not getting any clue how to do it...

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("update tblTeams set SchoolName='"+txtBoxSName.Text+"',TeamName='"+txtBoxTName.Text+"'where ID='"+txtBoxID.Text+"' ", con); 

con.Open();
sda.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Above piece of code updates the database but not in URDU, in database only "?????" shows...

In SQL server all the insert, update and delete works but I want to do it in front end...

Form design is also attached...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFvfG.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you heard of SQL injection? https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: What data types are your columns?  NVARCHAR, NCHAR and NTEXT would be used to support unicode.  If your columns are of those data types, have you tried putting an N before your strings in your DML statements?  i.e. something like SET SchoolName = N'SomeUrduValue'

Comment: Wait! **Don't use the second part of the update code.** It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use `parameters` in both, like you did in the first.

Comment: Using parameters is the right way to do this. But you should also not use AddWithValue. It can get things wrong sometimes. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with updation also and thanks for your support...
Here is the code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tblTeams set SchoolName=@SchoolName, TeamName=@TeamName where ID=@ID ", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtBoxID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolName", txtBoxSName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", txtBoxTName.Text);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score -1):

1. This is most likely happening because your columns don't support Unicode. You'll need to use `nvarchar`, or `nchar` in your columns.
2. Alternatively, your `TextBox` doesn't support `unicode` text. Try a different font, like Arial.
3. **Don't use the update code without Parameters**. It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use parameters in both, like you did in the first.

Finally, you can prefix the insert values with `N'urdutexthere'`, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblTeams SET SchoolName=N'@SchoolName',TeamName=N'@TeamName' WHERE ID='@ID'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtBoxID.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolName", txtBoxSName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TeamName", txtBoxTName.Text);

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: I have used the datatype as nvarchar in my tablle.

Comment: Then it's possible that your textboxes don't support unicode. Try changing the font. Also, you *really* need to be using [SQL Parameters](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter). Your update code is very, very hackable.

Comment: WHERE in your table? The columns you're inserting Urdu into, are they all `nvarchar`?

Comment: @Downvoter, is there something wrong with my suggestion? I would appreciate learning more.

Comment: `ntext` is deprecated - don't use it, don't recommend it - use `nvarchar(max)` instead

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I removed that.